# Detail view is not displaying content of models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-class-based-views

My detail View in Django, isn't successfully displaying the content selected from the listviews. The following is my code.

**Models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Post_Model(models.Model):

    Title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(Self):
        return Self.Title + ' | ' + str(Self.Author)
```

**urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Article_details, Home_page

urlpatterns = [
    path('', Home_page.as_view(), name="Home"),
    path('Article/<int:pk>/', Article_details.as_view(), name="Article"),
```

**Views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from . models import Post_Model

class Home_page(ListView):
    model = Post_Model
    template_name = 'June11App/Home.html'

class Article_details(DetailView):
    model = Post_Model
    template_name = 'June11App/Article.html'
```

**Html list view:**

```
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
<ul>
    {% for Post in object_list %}
<li>
    <a href="{% url 'Article' Post.pk  %}"> 
        {{Post.Title}} 
    </a>
    - {{Post.Author}}<br>
    {{Post.Body}}
</li>
<br>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Html detail view:**

```
<h1>Article Page</h1><br>

{{Post.Author}}
{{Post.Body}}
```

I hope my query made sense. I don't receive any error on myside, its just not working as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object data is passed as `object` and `post_model`, not `Post`, so:

```
<h1>Article Page</h1><br>

{{ object.Author }}
{{ object.Body }}
```

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `…Model` suffix. Therefore it might be better to rename <s>`Post_Model`</s> to `Post`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `author` instead of <s>`Author`</s>.